# QR scan plugin for Flutter (or Dart)

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, qr-code

I'm trying to find a QR scanner plugin that is stable and does not use any Firebase configuration. 
I've looked into the following, but some of them are old, no longer supported or depend on Firebase and other dependencies.

1. https://github.com/apptreesoftware/flutter_barcode_reader is no longer maintained.
2. https://github.com/rushio-consulting/flutter_camera_ml_vision requires Firebase integration.
3. https://github.com/juliuscanute/qr_code_scanner not sure if this is stable. No commit for 6 months now. But fits the bill.

Are there other QR scan libraries in Dart, that I can plug in to Flutter's Camera plugin myself?

Answer (score 0):

Im usind [qrScan](https://pub.dev/packages/qrscan) for my project and I didn't face any problem yet. I'ts also really easy to work with:

```
import 'package:qrscan/qrscan.dart' as scanner;


  Future _scan() async {
   String barcode = await scanner.scan();
   if (barcode == null) {
    print('nothing return.');
   } else {
    this._outputController.text = barcode;
   _displayDialog();
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

But If in case you are using

```
qrscan:
```

there may be some issues as there is a bug when your qrscan app is in background in scan position and start using camera of device using any other app  and after switching to your app your cammera will show error
also there is a problem for landscape mode
so try on your own risk